# Correct translation of "Nous en avons"?

Tags: pronoms, en

I have seen that "en" is placed between "Us/We,You,They" and a verb sometimes.
Example:

> Nous en avons discuté

I know what it means, but I don't understand what "en" is doing there. Why not

> Nous avons discuté

?

> We have discussed

Not

> We in have discussed

I assume that "en" means "in" in this case?

Answer (score 2):

For instance

> Nous avons discuté de la situation. => Nous en avons discuté.

`En` is a pronoun that replaces `de la situation`. It is not a preposition.

In English it would be conveyed by:

> We have discussed about it.

Usually in English one can omit `about it`. In French, it isn't so.

Other example:

> Il en avait compris l'importance => He had realized the importance (of it).

As a side remark, note that `en` as preposition is not always translated by `in`. E.g.

> En allant à l’université, j’ai rencontré une belle fille = While going to college I met a beautiful girl.

> Aller en Amérique = Go to America.

See https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-105600.php

Comment: You can actually omit it in French too, losing the same thing as in English (the reference to "the situation")... which will probably be implied anyway by the context