# Does "en" means "about it" in "Vous en avez trouvé une"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, en

I got a sentence about `en`.

> Vous en avez trouvé une.

The history is about looking for a solution.

> Vous avez cherché une solution et vous en avez trouvé une.

What does *en* mean in this case?

I know for example if I got the sentence *Vous en avez parlé*, then [*en* = *about it*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44580/correct-translation-of-nous-en-avons). But what does *en* mean in *Vous en avez trouvé une*?

Does *en* mean *about it* as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*En* is a pronoun here. It refers to *solution* and in this way, one avoids in French weird turns like

> Vous avez cherché une solution et vous avez trouvé une solution.

The correct turn is

> Vous avez cherché une solution et vous en avez trouvé une. → You looked for a solution and you found one.

Note that *en* is always present, in correct French, for expressions of quantity, including numerals and indefinites; usually it is not conveyed in English.

> Il en a pris une poignée. → He took a handful (of it).

> J'en ai trouvé huit. → I found eight (of them).

> Il n'en a pas d'autres. → He has not any others.

> On en a perdu quelques-uns. → We have lost some.